# SQL Statement for Reconciliation with different operators

Tags: sql, oracle, insert-update

This is very related to question: [SQL Statement for Reconciliation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817028/sql-statement-for-reconciliation) but with a more twist.

**Given the schema below:**

```
create table TBL1 (ID varchar2(100) primary key not null, MATCH_CRITERIA timestamp);
create table TBL2 (ID varchar2(100) primary key not null, MATCH_CRITERIA timestamp);
create table TBL_RESULT (ID varchar2(100) primary key not null, TBL1_ID varchar2(100), TBL2_ID varchar2(100));

create unique index UK_TBL_RESULT_TBL1_ID on TBL_RESULT(TBL1_ID);
create unique index UK_TBL_RESULT_TBL2_ID on TBL_RESULT(TBL2_ID);

insert into TBL1 VALUES('1', to_date('01/26/2012 20:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into TBL1 VALUES('2', to_date('01/26/2012 20:05:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

insert into TBL2 VALUES('3', to_date('01/26/2012 19:59:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into TBL2 VALUES('4', to_date('01/26/2012 20:04:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
```

**Our current query:**

```
INSERT INTO TBL_RESULT (ID, TBL1_ID, TBL2_ID) 
SELECT rawtohex(sys_guid()),t1.id,t2.id 
FROM
(SELECT t1.match_criteria,t1.id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.match_criteria ORDER BY t1.id) rn 
FROM tbl1 t1) t1,  
(SELECT t2.match_criteria,t2.id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.match_criteria ORDER BY t2.id) rn 
FROM tbl2 t2) t2
WHERE t1.match_criteria between t2.match_criteria - (10/1440) AND t2.match_criteria + (10/1440)
AND t1.rn=t2.rn
```

**It's output:**

```
| ID  |  TBL1_ID | TBL2_ID |
| '1' |  '1'     |    '3'  |
| '2' |  '1'     |    '4'  |
| '3' |  '2'     |    '3'  |
| '4' |  '2'     |    '4'  |
```

As you can see, results were not compliant to the unique constraint (duplicate TBL1_ID / duplicate TBL2_ID). This is because:

1. The RN for each record is always 1 (thus always equal)
2. The date between the two records is 10 minutes.

**We are expecting an output that looks like the table below:**

```
| ID  |  TBL1_ID | TBL2_ID |
| '1' |  '1'     |    '4'  |
| '2' |  '2'     |    '3'  |
```

Note 1: it doesn't matter if '1' is matched with '3', but then '2' should be matched to '4' to comply with the constraints and as long as the T1.MATCH_CRITERIA is within 10 minutes of T2.MATCH_CRITERIA.

Note 2: we are inserting a million records from TBL1 and another million records from TBL2. Thus, sequential insert using PL/SQL is not acceptable unless it can run really fast (less than 15 minutes).

Note 3: unmatched data should be eliminated. Unbalanced data is also expected.

Note 4: we are not limited to execute 1 query only. A series of finite queries will do.

Comment: What happens if there are rows in t1 that cannot be matched with rows in t2 (or vice versa)?  Do you eliminate that data?  Or would you expect to end up with output where either `TBL1_ID` or `TBL2_ID` would be NULL?

Comment: BTW your test data uses `MM` in the format mask twice.  You meant `MI` for minute the second time around.  It's a common mistake.

Comment: @JustinCave, eliminate the data.

Comment: @APC, thanks. I've modified it.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your query produces a cross join, because your business rules fail to provide a mechanism to link one record in T1 with just one record in T2.  Given that this is obviously a toy example it is difficult for us to suggest anything other than something very simplistic:

```
(SELECT t1.match_criteria,t1.id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t1.match_criteria,t1.id) rn 
.... 
(SELECT t2.match_criteria,t2.id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t2.match_criteria,t2.id) rn
```

This will simply match the first row in the T1 resultset with the first row in the T2 resultset, the second row in the T1 resultset with the second row in the T2 resultset, and so on.

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TBL_RESULT (ID, TBL1_ID, TBL2_ID) 
SELECT seq_tbl_result.nextval,t1.id,t2.id 
FROM
(SELECT t1.match_criteria,t1.id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t1.match_criteria, t1.id) rn 
FROM tbl1 t1) t1,  
(SELECT t2.match_criteria,t2.id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t2.match_criteria, t2.id) rn 
FROM tbl2 t2) t2
WHERE t1.match_criteria between t2.match_criteria - (10/1440) AND t2.match_criteria + (10/1440)
AND t1.rn=t2.rn
SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  
 10  /

2 rows created.


SQL> select * from tbl_result
  2  /

ID     TBL1_I TBL2_I
------ ------ ------
9      1      3
10     2      4

SQL>
```

That probably isn't what you want.  In which case you need to explain your data and the rules for deciding what links with what.  For instance is there some sort of pattern to either set of times which would allow you to derive an anchor point?

---

As an aside, when I rule the world people who use VARCHAR2(100) columns to hold numeric IDs will be shot.

Comment: The "aside" alone would warrant +1 :)

Comment: That's the only data. The query will not work given this data:    INSERT INTO TBL1 VALUES('1', TO_DATE('01/26/2012 01:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
insert into TBL1 VALUES('2', to_date('01/26/2012 02:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

insert into TBL2 VALUES('3', to_date('01/26/2012 02:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
INSERT INTO TBL2 VALUES('4', TO_DATE('01/26/2012 03:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

Answer (score 1):

I think this can work:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_RESULT (ID, TBL1_ID, TBL2_ID)
select seq_tbl_result.nextval,
tt1.id, tt2.id
from (select id, v, row_number() over(partition by v order by id) rn
from (select distinct t1.id,
case
when (t1.match_criteria between
t2.match_criteria - (10 / 1440) and
t2.match_criteria + (10 / 1440)) then
1
else
2
end v
from tbl1 t1, tbl2 t2
where t1.match_criteria between
t2.match_criteria - (10 / 1440) and
t2.match_criteria + (10 / 1440))) tt1,
(select id, v, row_number() over(partition by v order by id) rn
from (select distinct t2.id,
case
when (t1.match_criteria between
t2.match_criteria - (10 / 1440) and
t2.match_criteria + (10 / 1440)) then
1
else
2
end v
from tbl1 t1, tbl2 t2
where t1.match_criteria between
t2.match_criteria - (10 / 1440) and
t2.match_criteria + (10 / 1440))) tt2
where tt1.v = tt2.v
and tt1.rn = tt2.rn
```

Comment: Hi, I think v would always be 1. Anyway, I tried to jumble the data. Tbl 1 data (ordered by ID): 2AM, then 10 records with 1 minute interval starting at 1:01AM. Tbl 2 data (ordered by ID): 10 records with 1 minute interval starting at 1:01AM, then 2AM. Result: TBL1's 2AM was matched with TBL2's 1:01AM data. But I think you're already near...

Comment: Another scenario: TBl1 has 3 data: 01:00AM, 01:05AM, 02:00AM. TBL2 has 2 data only: 01:00AM, 02:00AM. TBL1's 01:00AM will be matched with TBL2's 01:00AM but TBL1's 01:05AM will be matched to TBL2's 02:00AM and TBL1's 02:00AM will not be matched.

Comment: You're right, v should somehow be dependent on t2.matched_criteria